# How can I increase the speed of my DQN neural network by TensorFlow 2.7?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

My computer configuration:

GPU: RTX 970, 4G memory

OS:windows 10 professional

CPU: intel Xeon E5 2680 v2*2

RAM: 128G

I use TensorFlow 2.7 to create a DQN neural network to solve GYM's MountainCar problem.

[Source code is here:](https://github.com/jaried/Tensorflow/blob/main/MountainCar.py)

I used debug mode and found that the `self.target_net.predict()` function and the `self.evaluate_net.predict()` function takes about `70ms` to run once.

```
%timeit qs = self.evaluate_net.predict(observation[np.newaxis])
75.6 ms ± 1.16 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

However, when I debug the `build_network()` function and use `model.summary()`, all parameters of a neural network are only 4547.
In other codes, I built a CNN Neural Network with 1.6M parameters and a total of 9 layers, and the time to run once was only `8ms`.
What is the reason why the neural network runs slowly once?

```
model.summary()
Model: "sequential_1"
___________________________________________________
 Layer (type) Output Shape Param #
===================================================== ===============
 dense_3 (Dense) (None, 64) 192
                                                                 
 dense_4 (Dense) (None, 64) 4160
                                                                 
 dense_5 (Dense) (None, 3) 195
                                                                 
===================================================== ===============
Total params: 4,547
Trainable params: 4,547
Non-trainable params: 0
___________________________________________________
```

The difference between the two codes is that the code that needs to be optimized has the following hints. Does it have anything to do with this? I checked stackoverflow and it says that Tensorflow needs to be recompiled from source：

```
I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations: AVX
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
```

I uninstalled TensorFlow, and  according to the [Intel® Optimization for TensorFlow* Installation Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/guide/optimization-for-tensorflow-installation-guide.html), after installing intel_tensorflow 2.7, it runs slower, and using `gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices(device_type='GPU')`, the GPU cannot be found. And the above prompt still appears.

I also tried `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS = 1` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to optimize a little bit:
[predict manual](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential#predict)
, so, I changed the two functions of DQNAgent, and the time was increased from 70 seconds per round to 35 seconds per round, and `the speed was doubled`.

The modified code is as follows:

```
class DQNAgent:
    
    def learn(self, observation, action, reward, next_observation, done):
        self.replayer.store(observation, action, reward, next_observation, done)  # store experience

        # Experience playback
        observations, actions, rewards, next_observations, dones = self.replayer.sample(self.batch_size)
        next_qs = self.target_net(next_observations)
        next_max_qs = next_qs.numpy().max(axis=-1)
        us = rewards + self.gamma * (1. - dones) * next_max_qs
        targets = self.evaluate_net(observations).numpy()
        targets[np.arange(us.shape[0]), actions] = us
        self.evaluate_net.fit(observations, targets, verbose=0)

        if done:  # update target network
            self.target_net.set_weights(self.evaluate_net.get_weights())
        return

    def decide(self, observation):  # epsilon greedy strategy
        if np.random.rand() < self.epsilon:
            return np.random.randint(self.action_n)
        qs = self.evaluate_net(observation[np.newaxis])
        return np.argmax(qs)
```

Now I just need to optimize this code:

```
self.evaluate_net.fit(observations, targets, verbose=0)
```

At one point I thought that there was something wrong with my algorithm. Later found that the following code can solve the MountainCar problem.

https://github.com/DanielPalaio/MountainCar-v0_DeepRL

Comparing his algorithm with mine, the difference is that the size of his hidden layer network is [256,256]
, my hidden layer is [64,64].
After I change the hidden layer directly to [1024,1024], my code can also solve the MountainCar problem.

In addition, his code uses tf.train_on_batch(), mine is tf.fit(), and running tf.train_on_batch() on my computer reports an error, so I had to change it to tf.fit().

I think the efficiency of DQN is very slow, DoubleDQN and DuelingDQN are indeed faster than DQN.